# how to update index directory using lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have a java program which indexes and searches some files for a keyword. I have 10 files in a `filestoindex` directory, and am indexing those files. When I run `IndexWriter` for first time it is showing that 10 documents have been indexed, but when I run it next time it is showing that it has indexed 20 documents.  To avoid this every time, I am removing the index directory and running the code.  When I do this it is working well.  Please suggest to me a way to update the index directory every time, when I run my `IndexWriter` (without deleting indexdir directory).

```
indexDirectory = new File(indexFilePath);
FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(D://filestoindex);
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer);
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `OpenMode` in `IndexWriterConfig` to [`CREATE`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html#CREATE).  This will cause it to start a new index when you open the `IndexWriter`, overwriting the old one if it exists.

```
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_34, analyzer);
config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
```